# Pass a variable to a PHP function, even if undefined

Tags: php

I discovered something that could clean up my code but I wanted to see ask the community to ensure this is not a loophole/bug.

Ok I have a config class like this

```
$this->config->items
```

I want to initiate another class that may have a config element or it may not. I understand there are a couple of ways to do this:

```
if(isset($this->config->xxxx)){
    return new SomeClass($this->config->xxxx);
} else {
    return new SomeClass();
}
```

or

```
$config = ! empty($this->config->xxxx) ? $this->config->xxxx : null;
return new SomeClass($config);
```

but I found out the following works great, just not sure if safe to use... AKA not how the compiler should work and will be patched.

```
return new SomeClass($c =& $this->config->xxxx);
```

I am using PHP 5.6.3 and the above works great and bench marks are negligible. From my understanding of PHP this is a valid way to do things but just wanted to make sure I was not missing anything. Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Comment: i really didnt get what you mean by `=& `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Explicitly stating your intended goals in code is preferable to implying them. If your code says `if..isset..else`, that's very clear. `( =& )` is not.
2. Verboseness trumps terseness most of the time. You're writing for humans, not for computers. The computer will do the same in the end either way.
3. Don't rely on weird side effects of code which is meant for other purposes. `=&` is not an "empty property error suppression operator", don't use it as such.
4. Try to avoid getting into the situation in the first place. Meaning your config class should probably always have all properties set, but they may be `null`; or you could use an explicit API call `$config->get('xxxx')` which can handle the absence of values internally, without needing to expose the error handling of absent values to the outside world.

   Ideally your code looks like this:

   ```
   return new SomeClass($this->config->get('xxx'));
   ```

   or even:

   ```
   return new SomeClass($this->config);
   ```

   or even:

   ```
   return SomeClass::withConfig($this->config);
   ```

   Implemented like:

   ```
   class SomeClass {

       public function __construct($xxx) { .. }

       public static function withConfig(Config $config) {
           return new static($config->get('xxxx'));
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: why have you assigned `Config` before `$config`